# How to Cancel NSURLSessionDataTask 'Inside' A RACSignal

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, nsurlsessiondatatask, racsignal

I am using Reactive Cocoa to merge & collect multiple network requests together (as RACSignals) like so:

```
[[[RACSignal merge:requestSignals] collect] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *results){...}
```

Each individual RACSignal is created like so:

```
- (RACSignal *)signalForMyRequest { RACSignal *signal = 
      [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable  
          (id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
              NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self myRequest success:nil failure:nil];
              return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
              [task cancel];
        }];
    }];

    return signal;
}
```

This all works fine. My question is this: is there a way to cancel the actual request (i.e. the `NSURLSessionDataTask`) inside of an individual RAC signal? I am using a `subscribeNext:` block on the merged signal, which returns a `RACDisposable` - which I can dispose, but that applies to the entire merge operation rather than an individual signal. I was looking at things like `takeUntil:` but this is described as "releasing the signal" and I'm not certain if that will in turn cancel the request it contains or not. Any help is appreciated.